# Flask + Vue -- Cookie authentification refresh token not working?

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, axios, flask-jwt-extended

I am creating a web app with Flask and Vue.js...
I got everything working so far but when the access token expires, the refresh process doesn't work.

Cookies seem to be set in browser correctly:
[image: Cookies in Browser]

Here is the important flask configuration:

```
...    
app.config["JWT_TOKEN_LOCATION"] = ["cookies"]
app.config["JWT_ACCESS_CSRF_HEADER_NAME"] = "X-CSRF-TOKEN-ACCESS"
app.config["JWT_REFRESH_CSRF_HEADER_NAME"] = "X-CSRF-TOKEN-REFRESH"
...
@app.route("/api/refresh", methods=["POST"])
@jwt_required(refresh=True)
def refresh():
    userid = get_jwt_identity()
    user = User.query.filter_by(id=userid).first()
    access_token = create_access_token(identity=user.id)

    resp = jsonify()
    set_access_cookies(resp, access_token)

    return resp, 201
```

Here is the axios configuration in vue:

```
const authServ = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_AUTH_URL,
    withCredentials: true,
    xsrfCookieName: 'X-CSRF-TOKEN-ACCESS'
});

const COOKIE_EXPIRED_MSG = "Token has expired";
authServ.interceptors.response.use(resp => {
    return resp;
}, async (error) => {
    const error_msg = error.response.data.msg;
    switch (error.response.status) {
        case 401:
            if (!error.config.retry && error_msg === COOKIE_EXPIRED_MSG) {
                error.config.retry = true;
                authServ.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'X-CSRF-TOKEN-REFRESH';
                await authServ.post('/refresh')
                authServ.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'X-CSRF-TOKEN-ACCESS';
                return authServ(error.config);
            }
            break;
        case 404:
            await router.push('/404');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return error.response;
});
```

**EDIT 1:**
The error message in the browser:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401
> (UNAUTHORIZED)

**EDIT 2:**
Fixed it by changing the method to *GET*, I would still like to know why though so if anyone has an idea... ^^

Comment: resp = jsonify() seems a little suspect, are you sure you didnt mean resp = jsonify({"message": "ok"}) or at least anything that can be jsonified? Also, what part of your code fails? the backend flask route or frontend code, for example a 500 status_code?

Comment: This is interesting, I'll be watching this

Comment: @c8999c3f964f64 Yeah maybe... But this should just be an empty json string shouldn't it? The part needed i thought is the cookie setting since i don't really do anything with the json response

Comment: I'm saying this because an empty json body is actually invalid json, both in the request as well as in the response. at the very, very least, use something like {} as a body

Comment: @c8999c3f964f64 I have tried adding {} as an empty dict as well as a {"success": True} to the response... Rest is left unchanged... It still doesn't work D:

Comment: @c8999c3f964f64 I just noticed you asking for what failed, i will add it in the initial question as an edit :)

Comment: Glad you could solve it! is it possible you had a mismatch with GET and POST, so the  backend was returning a 403 "Method not allowed", and this wasn't handled correctly by the frontend?